# Set of sequences - find the subset that together is a given sequence

Tags: algorithm

I have a lot of sequences with length 10 consisting of 0's and 1's. For instance:

```
1010100000 
1011000001
1011100010
1100000100
0011111011
```

Ect.

I want to find the sequences that collectively have a 0 in each column.  For instance, the algorithm should return these two:

```
1100000100
0011111011
```

and these three:

```
1100110000
0011111111
1111001111
```

etc.

Is there an algorithm for this?

Comment: What doe "together" mean? Add them , and them ? or them ? Looks like XOR to me. Also, look up "de Bruin graphs"

Comment: your second example has only 9 0's in.

Comment: I think he means just a 'sequence' of zeroes. am I right?

Comment: "Together" means that the result should be a set of sequences where we only have one sequence that starts with a '0', only one sequence with a '0' on the second place ect. and for every i in {1,.., 10} we should have a sequence with a 0 on the ith place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are describing is a restricted case of the [exact cover problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover_problem) where you want to find all solutions.  The general version of this problem is NP-hard, so there is no known efficient general algorithm for this larger problem.

To find all possible solutions, you could try listing all subsets of the bitvectors and test whether each has exactly one 0 in each column.  You could also consider implementing a backtracking search algorithm to try picking all subsets, but which stops searching down paths that can't possibly work (for example, paths containing two bitvectors with 0's in the same column).  If you want, you could try to implement the [dancing links algorithm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links), which was specifically designed to list off all solutions to this general problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'll try to figure something out.